# IDataErrorInfo doesn't work

Tags: c#, xaml, textbox, idataerrorinfo

I want to have the textbox's border red and another textbox under it telling the error.

C#

```
 class BandsVM : ObservableObject, IPage, IDataErrorInfo
    {

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "De naam is verplicht")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z''-'\s]{1,40}$", ErrorMessage = "Er zijn geen speciale tekens toegelaten")]
        [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 1, ErrorMessage = "De naam moet tussen de 1 en 50 karakters bevatten ")]
        private string insertName;
        public string InsertName
        {
            get { return insertName;  }
            set { insertName = value; }
        }
```

XAML:

```
<TextBox Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource ErrorTemplate}" Text="{Binding InsertName, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Style="{StaticResource TextboxError}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're inheriting from ObservableObject, which I'm assuming implements INotifyPropertyChanged

The property InsertName should invoke the PropertyChanged event handler, to notify the wpf binding engine to evaluate the property change. This will then invoke your this[] index , which the IDataErrorInfo uses to evaluate validation errors.

Change your property to this:

```
public string InsertName
{
    get { return insertName;  }
    set { 
        if (value != insertname)
        {
            insertName = value; 
        }

        OnPropertyChanged(() => InsertName);
        // or OnPropertyChanged("InsertName");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello MIchael, Thanks for your response, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried setting a break point on the set accessor of the property, to be sure that the binding is actually occurring correctly? Are you getting any errors in the output window?

Comment: Very strange, it goes trough the if well. But still the style isn't applied.

Comment: I would try removing the Validation.ErrorTemplate and the Style for the time being, just to verify that the default validation template works. If the default red border shows up, then post the relevant xaml for the validation template and textbox style.